# database connection time expired issue

Tags: sql-server, network

I have a server machine and four client machine for database connectivity.

I installed sqlexpress 2008 in server and one machine and all remaining systems, they have connected the database through the EMS (SQL Manager 2008 for SQL Server ).

The issue is that when I connect the database from that m/c which has sqlexpress 2008 then it gives "Timeout Expired"

But all remaining systems connect to server easily.

Why it gives an error for that particular system.

Comment: So you're timing out before you even connect?

Comment: yes, only one system have timeout expire problem

Comment: What is different about that system from the others?  Is the firewall turned on, is it on a different subnet, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Some things I'd check:

- When you connect from SQL Server Management Studio 2008 on the box with Express, are you using the right server name (and possibly port number)?
- Have you got Windows Firewall enabled on any of the machines?
- Can you ping the SQL Server?  Do you get the same IP address for it that you get on the other machines?
- Do you have any aliases set up in SQL Server Configuration Manager?
- Have you disabled any client protocols in SSCM?